# why is it called two's complement?

Tags: java, bit, twos-complement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [two's complement, why the name “two”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604296/twos-complement-why-the-name-two)

why is using a sign bit so to represent negative numbers is call "2's complement"? How did such name come about, can anyone explain it in a simple way, thanks a lot. By the way, if not using a sign bit, does that mean that there is no way of representing a negative number? Sorry, if it may be too big a question to ask here, I just wanna to really sort this straight in my head. Now, it's too messey.

Comment: careful here, Two's Complement is not exactly using a "sign" bit. Wikipedia actually explains it quite nicely: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: Mostly because "1's complement" was already taken.

Comment: In terms of representing a negative number, it can be done many ways, though most involve the "moral equivalent" of a sign bit.  You can, eg, have a "biased" number -- say one byte -- where the first 64 values represent negative numbers (counting from -64 to -1) and the next 192 represent positive numbers.  Tricky to do arithmetic with such values, but they are sometimes used for compactness.