# Understanding two's complement and one's complement

Tags: twos-complement

There are two quotes in my textbook (Patterson, 5th edition, Computer Organization) I don't get:

First:

> Two’s complement gets its name from the rule that the unsigned sum of an n-bit number and its n-bit negative is 2^n; hence, the negation or complement of a number x is 2^n - x, or its “two’s complement.”

Say I have a 4 bit number 2 = 0010
and it's negative = -2 = 1110

If I add them, I get 10000 (is this overflow? is this bad?) which is 16 right? And 1110 unsigned is 14? Is that what that quote is saying?

and

> A third alternative representation to two’s complement and sign and magnitude is called one’s complement. The negative of a one’s complement is found by inverting each bit, from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0, or x. This relation helps explain its name since the complement of x is 2^n - x - 1.

What does that mean? Can you give an example to help me see why the name is this way?

Say we have the binary representation of 2:

2 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010

In one's complement, the negation is:

-2 = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101

Is that the negative? If so, how is it 2^n - x - 1?

## --------------------

I understand two's complement:

> Simply invert every 0 to 1 and every 1 to 0, then add one to the result. This shortcut is based on the observation that the sum of a number and its inverted representation must be 111... (32 of them) 111, which represents -1.

So 2 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010

if we negate 2:

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101

and add 1:

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110

which is = -2

But I'm a bit confused about one's complement. Is it just two's complement without the addition of 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [two's complement, why the name "two"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604296/twos-complement-why-the-name-two)    An excellent answer is given there which explains the naming.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question though?

Comment: Well, I see a lot of question marks in your post. Maybe the question should be phrased to be more specific, and put aside the fact you already understand from the other answer provided above. For example, the other answer already provide the origin of the word two's complement.